# Change the color of map elements with a unique ID

Tags: openlayers, features

How can I change the color of a point or a Line by choosing its unique idea?

The problem is that this choice must be possible for several elements at the same time and these IDs are sent from the server.

These are the IDs I have, I want to be selected with osm_id.
[image]

I implemented it with the ability to click.

I work with GeoServer 2.20.4 and OpenLayers 6

```
var view = new ol.View({
  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0,0]),
  zoom: 12
});

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
     var proj = projection.getCode();
     var url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&' +
         'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=MashhadMap:roads-line&' +
         'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=' + proj + '&' +
         'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',' + proj;
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', url);
     var onError = function() {
       vectorSource.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
       failure();
     }
     xhr.onerror = onError;
     xhr.onload = function() {
       if (xhr.status == 200) {
         var features = vectorSource.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText);
         vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
         success(features);
       } else {
         onError();
       }
     }
     xhr.send();
   },
   strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
 });
 var stations = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
     var proj = projection.getCode();
     var url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&' +
         'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=MashhadMap:stations-point&' +
         'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=' + proj + '&' +
         'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',' + proj;
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', url);
     var onError = function() {
      stations.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
       failure();
     }
     xhr.onerror = onError;
     xhr.onload = function() {
       if (xhr.status == 200) {
         var features = stations.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText);
         stations.addFeatures(features);
         success(features);
       } else {
         onError();
       }
     }
     xhr.send();
   },
   strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
 });
//****************** SELECTED ELEMENT LAYER ******************/
 const selectedRoads = new ol.style.Style({
  // fill: new ol.style.Fill({
  //   color: '#eeeeee',
  // }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'yellow',
    width: 2,
  }),
});

const selectedStations = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'red',
    }),
    radius: 4
  })
});
// var feature = new ol.Feature({
//   setStyle : selectedStations,

// });
//  feature.setProperties('osm_id',5162991969);


var selectSingleClick1 = new ol.interaction.Select({
  layers: function(layer) {
    return layer.get('selectable') == true;
  },
  style: [selectedRoads,selectedStations]
});
//****************** END SELECTED ELEMENT LAYER ******************/

var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
  id: 'roads',
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'green',
          width: 3
      })
  })
});
var layerStations = new ol.layer.Vector({
  id: 'stations',
  source: stations,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#eeeeee',
      }),
      radius: 4
    })
  })
});
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    //interactions: selectSingleClick1,
    layers: [layerWFS,layerStations],
    view: view
  });

  map.getInteractions().extend([selectSingleClick1]);
  
  layerWFS.set('selectable', true);
  layerStations.set('selectable', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your GeoJSON features have unique id as feature attribute `id`, this becomes also OL feature id, and then you can retrieve this feature from layer source by `.getFeatureById` method. You can then set style of this feature with the `.setStyle` method:

```
vectorSource.getFeatureById(featureId).setStyle(newStyle);
```

To reset style to the original style, just use `.setStyle` without argument:

```
vectorSource.getFeatureById(featureId).setStyle();
```

Comment: vectorSource.getFeatureById(featureId) is **null** Returns
@tomazicm

Comment: This means that GeoJSON features have no id on feature level, maybe there is one in properties. Please edit your question and add a sample of feature.

Comment: I just met openLayers, can you help me more?

Comment: Please add a sample of GeoJSON feature from result of `http://localhost:8080/geoserverows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature ...` call.

Comment: It is not true?
`loader: function(extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
     var proj = projection.getCode();
     var url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&' +
         'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=MashhadMap:roads-line&' +
         'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=' + proj + '&' +
         'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',' + proj;
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', url);
     }
     xhr.send(); ...
   },
 });`
I put this in my code!!!

Comment: Not the call, result of the call, which looks something like `{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"AFG","properties":{"name":"Afghanistan"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[61.210817,35.650072], ...`

Comment: Explain completely in a separate answer, Because I do not pay full attention.